# Get a list of coordinates from System.Windows.Media.Geometry

Tags: c#, wpf

Given a `System.Windows.Media.Geometry` class instance, is there an easy way to convert this to a list of outlines and points? For example, how could I simply break this down into a list of `LineSegments` for custom rendering.

```
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText( "Hello", ...);
Geometry textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
```

How to list each of the outlines (where O would be an inside/outside circle) and each of the points on each outline?

As per the answer below;

```
    var flatten = textGeometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
    PathFigureCollection pfc = flatten.Figures;

    foreach (PathFigure pf in pfc)
     {
        foreach (PathSegment ps in pf.Segments)
         {
            if (ps is LineSegment)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `Geometry` class, you can use `GetFlattenedPathGeometry()`, `GetOutlinedPathGeometry()` (or related - decide what you actually want)  to get a `PathGeometry` and then query the `Figures` to get a list of figures.  Each of these `PathFigure` objects has the segments (which may be line segments, bezier, etc).

Note that in doing this, you may lose some information if you do it naively - if any arbitrary Geometry can be given, you will probably need to do more than just call FlattenedPathGeometry to not lose things like fill information.